# Refactoring 2 identical functions which receive a callback Func<Task<T>> and Func<T> respectively

Tags: c#, multithreading, generics, async-await, task

```
public static async Task<T> NDC<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    using (SomeDisposable())
    {
        try
        {
            return await func();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");

            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static T NDC<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    using (SomeDisposable())
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, these two functions are almost identical. The only difference between them is that when the callback is a `Func<Task<T>>` then it will be awaited and so that the return type is a `Task<T>`, otherwise, the function will return type `T`.

I want to group/generic these functions, any way I can achieve that? Thanks in advance.

P.S. If the caller called the non-tasked version, all the processes within this function should run within a single thread.

Comment: There is a reason that library authors provide both sync and async variants of methods...they are designed to be invoked differently and carry different semantics.  This is a bad use of DRY and ultimately will lead to hard-to-maintain code.

Comment: Also, consider that with the introduction of `IAsyncDisposable`, even wrapping disposables in using statements may not use the same implementation.

Comment: Let me remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could derive the synchronous version from the asynchronous one, like this:

```
public static T NDC<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));
    return NDC(() => Task.FromResult(func())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

There are two gotchas:

1. You can't get away by doing the argument validation in only one method. You must validate the `func` argument in both `NDC` methods. Unless you use nullable reference types, as Alexei Levenkov [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486338/refactoring-2-identical-functions-which-receive-a-callback-functaskt-and-fun/65487511#comment115783090_65487511) in the comments.
2. This solution only works if the `await func();` is the only awaited operation inside the asynchronous `NDC` method. Otherwise the current thread will be blocked, and bad things are going to happen (either scalability degradation or a deadlock, depending on the type of the application).

Comment: Seems if I do it in this way, I will still enter multi-thread circumstance which is I want to avoid

Comment: @mannok I don't see how concurrency could occur, unless there are other awaited operations inside the `NDC` method, that you have not shown to us.

Comment: Good point that you can actually hack up sync version by knowing that async one will not actually run async with synchronous callback... Couple notes: for C# 9 you have nullable reference types which let you skip that null check... And really since there no asynchronous execution in this case you could just do `.Result`... (if `NDC` has actual async calls in addition to that there is really no good reason to try to combine them)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am not a big fan of the nullable refs concept. I am seeing all these curly question marks popping out everywhere as language polution. :-) Regarding using the `.Result` property, won't this wrap a possible exception in an `AggregateException`?